# Converting ASCII/Base64 string to Hexadecimal in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, base64, hex, ascii

My input data is an array of ASCII values:

```
[103, 81, 70, 72, 65, 65, 111, 66, 71, 65, 77, 69, 67, 81, 73, 65, 65, 78, 67, 117]
```

Each element of the above array is the ASCII value of the Base64 string:  `"gQFHAAoBGAMECQIAANCu"`

I want to convert this Base64 string to hexadecimal bytes as : `81 01 0f 00 0a 01 18 03 04 09 03 00 00 81 6e`.

My approach so far:

```js
function Decode(bytes) {
  var base64String = b2s(bytes);
  var HexValue = toHex(base64String);
  return HexValue;
}

function b2s(array) {
  return String.fromCharCode.apply(String, array);
}


function toHex(str) {
  var result = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    result += str.charCodeAt(i).toString(16);
  }
  return result;
}

const data = Decode([103, 81, 70, 72, 65, 65, 111, 66, 71, 65, 77, 69, 67, 81, 73, 65, 65, 78, 67, 117])
console.log(data);
```

The above code snippet gives me: `"6751464841416f4247414d4543514941414e4375"`, which is a Hex string. I found some StackOverflow questions suggesting the following code snippet:

```
function base64ToHex(str) {
  const raw = atob(str);
  let result = '';
  for (let i = 0; i < raw.length; i++) {
    const hex = raw.charCodeAt(i).toString(16);
    result += (hex.length === 2 ? hex : '0' + hex);
  }
  return result.toUpperCase();
}
```

However, the `atob` is not available in my implementation.

Did I miss anything in my approach? Any help will be highly appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: If you want to do some light reading :) the algorithm that `atob` uses is described in https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4648

Comment: There is also a polifill for `atob` that may help you look at it differently - https://github.com/MaxArt2501/base64-js/blob/master/base64.js#L54

Comment: btw I got this info from the MDN docs for `atob` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/atob

Comment: The platform where I use JavaScript is Thingsboard. It does not support atob.

Comment: I know because you mentioned that in your question. My comments give you information on how `atob` works so you can create your own implementation.